# macOS M1 Imagick missing symbol called

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick, php-extension

I installed ImageMagick and installed Imagick with PECL, but I'm getting an error when I add it to the php.ini file.:

> missing symbol called
>
> zsh: abort

macOS Ventura 13.5.2
XAMPP 8.1.17

Comment: You didn't show what you added to the `php.ini` file.